# What is the output of "grails stats" for your largest Grails project?

Tags: grails

`grails stats` gives various code statistics for a given Grails project.

Typical output can look like something along the lines of:

```
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Name                 | Files |  LOC  |
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Controllers          |     4 |   183 | 
| Domain Classes       |     8 |   264 | 
| Jobs                 |     1 |    10 | 
| Services             |     4 |   297 | 
| Tag Libraries        |     2 |    63 | 
| Unit Tests           |    17 |   204 | 
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Totals               |    36 |  1021 | 
+----------------------+-------+-------+
```

I'm curious about the typical division of code between the various artifacts in Grails projects (such as the ratio LOC(controllers) / LOC(services), etc.).

**Please share the `grails stats` output of your largest Grails project to contribute your statistics to this question.**

Comment: I tried making this a community wiki, but that checkbox was not available. Has the community wiki feature been removed from SO, or has the CW rules been altered?

Comment: The CW rules have changed (a while back), but I don't know their exact implementation currently. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183

Comment: Sorry, I don't even think this is on topic as a wiki.  We've never had a "I'll show you mine if you show me yours" question on StackOverflow.  I'm not even sure if this would be on-topic at programmers.SE.  Asking [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/would-this-question-be-on-topic-on-pse).

Comment: It's a GTKY question; strictly-speaking, they've never really been valid here... But once upon a time, CW-ing them would get others to look the other way. [They are now explicitly discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Strive to ask questions that don't set up *every response* as a valid answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My current project:

```
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Name                 | Files |  LOC  |
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Controllers          |    67 |  7665 | 
| Domain Classes       |   101 |  3736 | 
| Jobs                 |     3 |    45 | 
| Services             |    61 |  6158 | 
| Tag Libraries        |    34 |  2357 | 
| Groovy Helpers       |    54 |  3356 | 
| Java Helpers         |     1 |    65 | 
| Unit Tests           |   227 | 24224 | 
| Integration Tests    |    70 | 10908 | 
| Scripts              |     2 |    77 | 
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Totals               |   620 | 58591 | 
+----------------------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Does this number of controllers slow your application down? IIRC, a known Grails problem is that request time grows linearly by number of controllers.

Comment: I'm sure there is a small hit with the additional url mappings that need to be looked at, but nothing significant that we've seen.  The cleaner code far outweighs a millisecond or two on the response time.

Comment: That's optimistic - the hit is far more then a millisecond or two. Before 1.3.5, webservices performance suffered a lot from this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The large number in "Java Helpers" originates mostly from a wsdl2java stub generation.

```
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Name                 | Files |  LOC  |
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Controllers          |    13 |  1085 | 
| Domain Classes       |    17 |   802 | 
| Services             |    19 |  1918 | 
| Tag Libraries        |     2 |   182 | 
| Groovy Helpers       |    39 |  1586 | 
| Java Helpers         |   521 | 42232 | 
| Unit Tests           |    45 |  5294 | 
| Integration Tests    |     9 |   836 | 
| Scripts              |     2 |    22 | 
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Totals               |   667 | 53957 | 
+----------------------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Name                 | Files |  LOC  |
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Controllers          |    40 |  3912 |
| Domain Classes       |    42 |  2109 |
| Jobs                 |     5 |   127 |
| Services             |    18 |  2352 |
| Tag Libraries        |    12 |   355 |
| Groovy Helpers       |   158 |  5249 |
| Java Helpers         |     4 |   207 |
| Unit Tests           |    54 |  3258 |
| Integration Tests    |    22 |  1790 |
| Scripts              |     7 |   150 |
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Totals               |   362 | 19509 |
+----------------------+-------+-------+
```

A pity it doesn't have more stats like average/min/max LOC per class, test coverage, etc ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Name                 | Files |  LOC  |
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Controllers          |    17 |  1961 | 
| Domain Classes       |    14 |   843 | 
| Jobs                 |     4 |   109 | 
| Services             |     5 |   831 | 
| Tag Libraries        |     2 |   789 | 
| Groovy Helpers       |    38 |   948 | 
| Java Helpers         |     5 |   445 | 
| Unit Tests           |     1 |    12 | 
| Integration Tests    |     1 |    33 | 
| Scripts              |     1 |    11 | 
+----------------------+-------+-------+
| Totals               |    88 |  5982 | 
+----------------------+-------+-------+
```

Small app (about 25 stories)